# How to solve input/output shape error Conv1D (Temporal CNN)

Tags: time-series, conv-neural-network

I am running a Conv1D model in Keras. I get an error saying: "Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 4097)"

The input data frame I am giving to the model for each sample contains one row of 4097 timeseries signals (vibration data) and the output contains 8 classes. The shapes of my x and y for training and testing data are are as follows:

```
x_train.shape:(316, 4097)
y_test.shape:(1395, 8)
x_test.shape:(1395, 4097)
y_train.shape:(316, 8)
```

Followings are also my model components, I would appreciate if anyone familiar with this issue could guide me.

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_dim=x_train.shape[1]),
    MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2),
    Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
    MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2),
    Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
    MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2),
    Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
    MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='relu')
])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=2,epochs=200)
```

Kind regards,

Mostafa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the shape should be batch x length x channels, you are missing channel information. Reshape the data to

```
x_train.shape:(316, 4097,1)
y_test.shape:(1395, 8)
x_test.shape:(1395, 4097,1)
y_train.shape:(316, 8)
```

You can use `numpy.expand_dims` function for it.

Change `input_dim` to `x_train.shape[1::]` or `(4097,1)`